# How do regex ranges work with shorthand syntax?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am confused by this line of code in a JavaScript regular expression:

`.replace(/[^\w- ]+/g,'')`

I understand that it is trying to perform a replace on characters that are not in the word character class. But it is also a range so it must include others. I would assume maybe also the space character, but running this in the console it does not seem to replace it.

[^\w] would mean none of the following characters: a-zA-Z0-9_

How is a range possible here? What does \w- start from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\w-`  is not a character range because `\w` is not a character. The `-` here has no special meaning, so `[^\w- ]` matches anything that isn't a word character, a literal dash, or a space.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is not a valid range for the reason that `\w` is not a character. The hyphen at the position in your character class can't form a range and gets interpreted as a literal or as mistake. The regular expression matches any character except: word characters (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`), a hyphen (`-`) and a space character (`' '`).